# What form is this unicode string encoded in?

Tags: bash, curl, unicode, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to emulate the curl command that was generated from chrome developer tools.

The command is like this:

```
curl 'http://x.com/postmessage' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://prakard.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://x.com/postmessage' -H 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=rmuxos45bxhe4445y4ygtt45; yaf=yaf_Load; __utmz=96396509.1455869871.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _cbclose58589=1; _uid58589=63E1EF1E.4; __utma=96396509.558394442.1455869871.1456137877.1456147871.4; __utmc=96396509; YAF.NET_Authentication=XXXX; _cbclose=1; _ctout58589=1; verify=test; __utmb=96396509' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"\r\n\r\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\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"\r\n\r\nCA0B0334\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"\r\n\r\n/wEWBwKEptnyCgK9mvbUBwKR3c+MAQLTpZ7kBQLGqL2CCwLC2ayTBgL8j7b4C1actnyqRCkzYjl3a/EjOGSpG9Nt\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="forum$ctl00$edit"\r\n\r\n\xa2\xcd\xcd\xc0\xd1\xc2 \xe4\xc1\xe8\xbe\xba\xb7\xc3\xd1\xbe\xc2\xec\xb7\xd5\xe8\xa4\xd8\xb3\xcb\xd2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="forum$ctl00$PostReply"\r\n\r\nPost\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="forum$ctl00$scrollLeft"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="forum$ctl00$scrollTop"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEG92Qj6unfqGb8TW--\r\n' --compressed
```

The curious part here is :

```
\xa2\xcd\xcd\xc0\xd1\xc2 \xe4\xc1\xe8\xbe\xba\xb7\xc3\xd1\xbe\xc2\xec\xb7\xd5\xe8\xa4\xd8\xb3\xcb\xd2
```

Which is generated from original content :

```
ขออภัย ไม่พบทรัพย์ที่คุณหา
```

However, it is does not seem like UTF8 encoded string ?
Can anyone tell me how was string generated ?

Comment: just noticed : its windows-874 charset !

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer and close this question. I did not notice the charset encoding in chrome. it is `windows-874` . very obvious if I was looking at dev panel more closely.

[image: Chrome dev panel]

Comment: "very obvious if I was looking ... closely" :D

Comment: well i did waste 3 hours googling before posting here ! :D